# Making a domain more trustworthy to corporate networks so that it won't be blocked by their filters

Tags: domains, security, filtering, firewall

I developed a web app for a customer which is made in basic PHP/MySQL, pretty normal site, lighter than WordPress, and when my customer went to his client to sell the app the domain was blocked by the internal router.

He was first on the guest-WiFi, domain was blocked, but then they tried to plug his computer directly to the router with a cable, domain was still blocked. His clients are big factories, and I know those tends to have higher security on their local network.

I'm looking for solutions to make his domain trustworthy so this doesn't happen again when he presents what he has to sell. My research was not concluding enough for me as it just gives me examples to make the website LOOK more trustworthy or it's people having problems with their home network. Hence why I'm here looking for help.

Aside from manually white-listing his domain on each factories' network he visit, is there a solution?

The only thing I figured out so far is that it may be because his domain is young and only renewed for 1 year at a time, we suggested him to renew for 5 years at a time, but I fear that this won't be enough. Is there something to do in the DNS?

I sadly don't have any information of the factory's network setup and protections. I'm more looking for a solution that would work everywhere, if possible. Like Facebook will never be blocked anywhere because of its authority and trustworthiness, but how do I get a domain to that level of acceptance by security?

Domain name: hybpreventionconseil.ca

Comment: Every workplace has different security protocols. Some workplaces even block well known sites like Facebook. Why not ask him to use his own mobile network?

Comment: We will certainly tell him that, but was looking for possible solutions that would help my client without him doing anything first.

Comment: In my view, I don't think a reliable and universal solution exists that can ensure the domain is not blocked by local networks.

Comment: But I mean, not every domain are blocked by their local network security. What makes a domain pass the filters and others don't? I was looking to improve domain reputation so it would be considered as a non-threatening domain.

Comment: I feel that the filter that prevented your customer's domain may not even be related to security.  Many workplaces that I know allow/block websites based on several factors like impact on productivity. For example, a software support firm may block social media websites. In other cases, firms may allow only a handful of websites that they know could help the workers (like knowledgebase, subject forums, etc.).

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can definitively do - and most likely the corporate in question is running a whitelist.

There are a few things you can do which theoretically will make your site more trustworthy (in addition to a long domain registration).  Again,  none of these are anything close to a guarantee of acceptance, and the return on investment is likely not there to go out of your way -

1. Use an EV  certificate.  These are more expensive certs hsed in banking and the like. In addition to providing encryption they go some way to prove the relationship between a domain name and the correct owner - with issuers doing some (basic) checks on the business.
2. Consider using a service like Cloudflare - they put your site behind a reverse proxy, and this is a service typically used by more prpfessional businesses - and includes some security protections as well.
3. You can use CAA records to "pin" your https cert to your provider.
4. You can cryptographically sign your DNS.
5. Ensure you have privacy policy and (if you care about eu) Cookie acceptance crap.
6. Get a reputable seo entity to help you - entries in Moz and other credible databases cant hurt.